# Can't push to Github non-fast-forward error

Tags: git, github, github-pages, git-pull, fast-forward

I'm working on a site and I am using React-create-app and it's webpack configuration. I had been pushing to a Github repo without any issues. A couple days ago I turned the site I am making into a Github Pages site (i.e. mygithubname.github.io).

After turning this repo into a Github Pages site the structure of my project's repo changed. It looks like it minimized the code for the sake of putting it online. Once I pushed this repo and made it a live Github Pages site all of a sudden I couldn't push to the repo anymore.

If I push to the repo I get an error:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Nicknyr/New_Portfolio.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I have done some searching online and I have attempted to do a `git pull origin master` to correct the issue. If I try that it deletes 75% of my project and most of my components go missing. This is the result of `git pull origin master`:

```
git pull origin master
From https://github.com/Nicknyr/New_Portfolio
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Removing yarn.lock
CONFLICT (modify/delete): src/styles/_Projects.scss deleted in 5977716b3eb3a9424a9efdbf835a0a2ae9cf6f88 and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of src/styles/_Projects.scss left in tree.
CONFLICT (modify/delete): src/styles/_Info.scss deleted in 5977716b3eb3a9424a9efdbf835a0a2ae9cf6f88 and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of src/styles/_Info.scss left in tree.
Removing src/styles/_Header.scss
CONFLICT (modify/delete): src/styles/_Global.scss deleted in 5977716b3eb3a9424a9efdbf835a0a2ae9cf6f88 and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of src/styles/_Global.scss left in tree.
Removing src/styles/_Footer.scss
Removing src/styles/_ContactForm.scss
Removing src/styles/_Contact.scss
Removing src/registerServiceWorker.js
Removing src/logo.svg
Removing src/index.js
Removing src/index.css
Removing src/images/tic-tac-toe-medium.png
Removing src/images/steem-medium.png
Removing src/images/resume-new.png
Removing src/images/resume-medium.png
Removing src/images/redo.png
Removing src/images/pomodoro-small.png
Removing src/images/placeholder.png
Removing src/images/nodes-no-color.jpg
Removing src/images/name-logo.png
Removing src/images/name-logo-small.png
Removing src/images/euro-small.png
Removing src/images/euro-large.png
Removing src/images/euro-250.png
Removing src/images/centered.png
Removing src/images/blue-nodes-opacity.jpg
Removing src/images/background-2462434_1920.jpg
CONFLICT (modify/delete): src/Projects.js deleted in 5977716b3eb3a9424a9efdbf835a0a2ae9cf6f88 and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of src/Projects.js left in tree.
Removing src/NodeMailer.js
CONFLICT (modify/delete): src/Menu.js deleted in 5977716b3eb3a9424a9efdbf835a0a2ae9cf6f88 and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of src/Menu.js left in tree.
Removing src/Info.js
CONFLICT (modify/delete): src/Header.js deleted in 5977716b3eb3a9424a9efdbf835a0a2ae9cf6f88 and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of src/Header.js left in tree.
Removing src/Footer.js
Removing src/ContactForm.js
CONFLICT (modify/delete): src/Contact.js deleted in 5977716b3eb3a9424a9efdbf835a0a2ae9cf6f88 and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of src/Contact.js left in tree.
Removing src/App.test.js
Removing src/App.scss
CONFLICT (modify/delete): src/App.js deleted in 5977716b3eb3a9424a9efdbf835a0a2ae9cf6f88 and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of src/App.js left in tree.
CONFLICT (modify/delete): src/App.css deleted in 5977716b3eb3a9424a9efdbf835a0a2ae9cf6f88 and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of src/App.css left in tree.
Removing public/index.html
CONFLICT (modify/delete): package.json deleted in 5977716b3eb3a9424a9efdbf835a0a2ae9cf6f88 and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of package.json left in tree.
Removing README.md
Removing .gitignore
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

It deletes most of my project. I undid this via `git reset --hard`. I got my project files back but I still can't push to Github.

[Here is what happened to my repo](https://github.com/Nicknyr/nicknyr.github.io/commit/5977716b3eb3a9424a9efdbf835a0a2ae9cf6f88) after making my site into a Github Pages site. As you can see it deleted most of my project and this appears to be what I am reverting back to when I go `git pull origin master`.

How do I straighten this out? I want to get my branch on track so that I can continue pushing to it without losing all these files.

Comment: "It looks like it minimized the code for the sake of putting it online."—It looks like _what_ minimized the code? How did you "turn this repo into a Github Pages site"? What exactly did you do?

Comment: I changed the name of the repo to my Github username. I previously had another repo that used my user name. Could that be the root of my problem? After pushing to Github the structure of my repo changed.

Comment: You just changed your GitHub repo name? That literally cannot cause any changes to the structure of your repository.

Comment: I believe the changes made to the folder structure have to do with it being changed to a Github Pages site.

Comment: That's not how it works. Simply being a GitHub Pages site doesn't do anything to the structure of your files. Based on your comment about minified code it sounds like _you_ ran some minification process, committed those files, and then pushed to the new repo (possibly with `--force` or `--force-with-lease`, based on your comment that other code lived there before). GitHub Pages doesn't do anything to your source files.

Comment: The commit you link to is one that _you_ made, not something that GitHub Pages did. Your commit message "Updates" doesn't help explain what happened at all, but it looks like maybe you wiped out all of your source files and replaced them with the contents of the build directory?

Comment: Could this be the result of npm build or another npm command?

Comment: It may be related to running `npm build` of other commands, but it's a _result of_ you committing the changes, then pushing them to GitHub. Do you pay attention when you stage and commit files, adding the changes you ant and checking diffs etc., or just blindly do `git add . && git commit`? This error happened way before the code hit GitHub.

Comment: I didn't push any changes that removed all those files from my project. After running `npm build` does that affect the ability to continue to push to that repo?

Comment: Look at your local copy. Git is a _distributed_ version control system. Commits happen _on your machine_, and if they're appearing on GitHub that means you (well, somebody) pushed them. `npm build` can do literally anything; its behaviour is defined in your `package.json` file. It would be weird for it to interfere with Git, though.

Comment: If you're going to respond to a question on here and be snippy and condescending you're better off just not responding at all. You made no effort to answer the question or help me. Take your elitist nonsense elsewhere and get a hobby. I get it, you're smarter than I am.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was condescending. Maybe I could have been gentler but there's not a lot of room in these comments. In fact I _am_ trying to help you, by pointing out that this isn't something that happened to you; it's the result of whatever commands you ran. We need to know what those commands are if we're going to be able to help you. If one of those commands was `npm build` it would be helpful to know what your project's build script does. And this didn't happen on GitHub, it happened on your machine, which is why I'm asking you to look at your local copy.

Answer (score 0):

Make aure you have commited your files or directory

```
git add .
```

Or a file/directory name instead of "."

```
git commit --all

git push origin master
```

Also you need to make sure that you are not behind the already pushed code. If it is that so, this error will be raised

Comment: I've been doing that. The issue is the local files on my computer don't match up with the repo. But when I pull it deletes so many of my files.

Comment: In fact `git add .` might be the _cause of_ the OP's problem. It certainly isn't a solution. It's an antipattern that makes it much easier not to know what you're committing. Add the files (or chunks) you explicitly want to commit, verify with `git diff --cached`, and commit the changes you want to commit. Then check your diffs again, just to be safe. If you're pushing and creating a PR, take ten seconds to review the PR's diff. It's your responsibility to know what you're committing and merging.

Answer (score 0):

I try to make
**git pull-r**
then
**git push origin master**

okey